# find substring using match regex

Tags: java, regex

Using regex how to find a substring in other string. Here are two strings:

```
String a= "?drug <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/possibleDiseaseTarget> ?disease .";

String b = "?drug <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/molecularWeightAverage> ?weight . ?drug <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/possibleDiseaseTarget> ?disease";
```

I want to match only

`<http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/possibleDiseaseTarget>`

Comment: Why do you specifically need a regex when `contains` exists ?

Comment: it doesn't work at all :(

Comment: Can we see what [have you done so far to solve this problem](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: just used  if(b.contains(a)){}

Comment: @QaiserMehmood : It works perfecly fine, the fact is that b does not contain a. Remove the final point and the space in a, and it will return true.

Comment: @Dici I suspect that OP doesn't want to check if `b` contains `a`, but from strings like `a` and `b` **find** string described at bottom of question.

Comment: @Pshemo You may be true, I'll edit my answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is not quite HTML and any XML/HTML parser couldn't help it you can try with [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). It seems that you want to find text in form

```
?drug <someData> ?disease
```

To describe such text regex you need to escape `?` (it is one of regex special characters representing *[optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)* - zero or once - quantifier) so you need to place `\` before it (which in String needs to be written as `"\\"`).
Also part `<someData>` can be written as as `<[^>]>` which means,

- `<`,
- one or more non `>` after it,
- and finally `>`

So regex to match `?drug <someData> ?disease` can be written as

`"\\?drug <[^>]+> \\?disease"`

But since we are interested only in part `<[^>]+>` representing `<someData>` we need to let regex [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) founded contend. In short if we surround some part of regex with parenthesis, then string matched by this regex part will be placed in something we call group, so we will be able to get part from this group. In short final regex can look like

```
"\\?drug (<[^>]+>) \\?disease"
         ^^^^^^^^^---first group,
```

and can be used like

```
String a = "?drug <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/possibleDiseaseTarget> ?disease .";
String b = "?drug <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/molecularWeightAverage> ?weight . ?drug <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/possibleDiseaseTarget> ?disease";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\?drug (<[^>]+>) \\?disease");
Matcher m = p.matcher(a);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
System.out.println("-----------");
m = p.matcher(b);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

which will produce as output

```
<http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/possibleDiseaseTarget>
-----------
<http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/possibleDiseaseTarget>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use a regex here, just do this :

```
String substr = "<http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/possibleDiseaseTarget>";
System.out.println(b.contains(substr)); // prints true
System.out.println(a.contains(substr)); // prints true
```

Comment: it is not complete string but the part of "a". what I want is to match the complete string or some part of string "a". However, I have solved the problem by taking the substring(start, end) of "a" and it matches now.